# jquery call one script from another

Tags: php, jquery

this is part of code from online shop page. php code loads full catalog, after that jquery clicks on corresponding link and filters catalog.

i have two jqueries on a page and both of them work, BUT

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.side-menu-categories li', function () {
        var click = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $('.product-box').hide();
        $('.product-box').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('data-filter') == click || click == 0) {
                $(this).fadeIn('fast');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

this part is working good and i have no problem with it, but when i try to call it on window load it's not working

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#loader_spin').hide();
    $('#product_container').show();
    var clicked = false;
    var filter_catalog = <?php echo(isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0); ?>;
    $('.side-menu-categories li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-filter') == filter_catalog) {
            $(this).click();
            var clicked = true;
        }
    });
    if (clicked == false) {
        $('.side-menu-categories li[data-filter="0"]').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `(document).ready(` instead of `(window).load`? Sounds like a classical loading time problem.

Comment: i need this function on window load not document ready .. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `var clicked = true;` you are defining new variable into local scope of `each()` function, so remove `var` (i.e. just do `clicked = true`) in order to use global variable defined in `load()` scope above:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#loader_spin').hide();
    $('#product_container').show();
    var clicked = false;
    var filter_catalog = <?php echo(isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0); ?>;
    $('.side-menu-categories li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-filter') == filter_catalog) {
            $(this).click();
            clicked = true; //don't declare it locally
        }
    });
    if (clicked == false) {
        $('.side-menu-categories li[data-filter="0"]').click();
    }
});
```